# I want to add a background to my wordpress website in three.js, creating a wireframe I don't manage to put a sphere at the extremity of each line

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, orbitcontrols

So I have a turquoise diamond, I would like to add a directional camera from the camera. This will be a bg in a WordPress section (also don't know how to do.

So my issue here is I have created a wireframe here that is over the diamond, but I am trying to get 3d spheres to stick onto every intersection of lines, I don't know why it never seems to work, I have read the wireframe mesh page of three.js but nothing moves. what am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Amba</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"> -->

    <style>
        body {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Monospace;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 24px;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
}

a {
    color: #ff0;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

button {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 1; /* TODO Solve this in HTML */
}

a, button, input, select {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.lil-gui {
    z-index: 2 !important; /* TODO Solve this in HTML */
}

@media all and ( max-width: 640px ) {
    .lil-gui.root { 
        right: auto;
        top: auto;
        max-height: 50%;
        max-width: 80%;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
}

#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

    #overlay button {
        background: transparent;
        border: 0;
        border: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
        border-radius: 4px;
        color: #ffffff;
        padding: 12px 18px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

#notSupported {
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f00;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="importmap">
        {
            "imports": {
                "three": "../build/three.module.js",
                "three/addons/": "./jsm/",
                "three-subdivide": "https://unpkg.com/three-subdivide@1.1.2/build/index.module.js"
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script type="module">

      import * as THREE from 'three';
      import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';

      let camera, scene, renderer, controls;
      let diamond, wireframe, circle1, circle2;

      init();
      animate();

      function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 100);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
  // Directional light
  const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 1);
            scene.add(directionalLight);

              // Directional light
  const directionalLight2 = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0x008080, 1);
            directionalLight2.position.set(-1, 0, 2);
            scene.add(directionalLight2);
      // Create diamond geometry
      const diamondGeometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(3.5, 0);
            const diamondMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x008080, specular: 0x00ff00, shininess: 50 });
            diamond = new THREE.Mesh(diamondGeometry, diamondMaterial);
            scene.add(diamond);





            // // Create wireframe geometry
            // const wireframeGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(diamondGeometry);
            // const wireframeMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });

            // wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframeGeometry, wireframeMaterial, wireframeLinejoin );
            // wireframe.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1.5); // Double the size
    
            // scene.add(wireframe);
            // Create wireframe geometry
const wireframeGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(diamondGeometry);
const wireframeMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });

// Create wireframe using LineSegments
wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframeGeometry, wireframeMaterial);
wireframe.scale.set(1.5, 1.5, 1.5); // Double the size

// Add spheres at the end of each line segment
const vertices = diamondGeometry.attributes.position.array;
const numVertices = vertices.length / 3;

const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 16, 16);
const sphereMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });

for (let i = 0; i < numVertices; i++) {
    const x = vertices[i * 3];
    const y = vertices[i * 3 + 1];
    const z = vertices[i * 3 + 2];

    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sphereMaterial);
    sphere.position.set(x, y, z);
    scene.add(sphere);
}

scene.add(wireframe);

// mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
//     scene.add( mesh );
    

//      var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( wireframeGeometry, wireframeMaterial );
//     mesh.add( wireframe );

//     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
//     renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
//     document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

// Add circles at the ends of each line in the wireframe
                addCirclesAtWireframeEnds(wireframe);


        const circleGeometry1 = new THREE.CircleGeometry(0.2, 10);
        const circleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });
        circle1 = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry1, circleMaterial);
        scene.add(circle1);

        const circleGeometry2 = new THREE.CircleGeometry(0.2, 32);
        circle2 = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry2, circleMaterial);
        scene.add(circle2);

        const floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);
        const floorMaterial = new THREE.ShadowMaterial({ opacity: 0.5, color: new THREE.Color(1, 1, 1) });
        const floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
        floor.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
        floor.position.y = -3.5; // Adjusted the position to be below the diamond
        floor.receiveShadow = true;
        scene.add(floor);

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.enableDamping = true;
controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
controls.screenSpacePanning = false;
controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2;
controls.enableZoom = false; // Disable zooming

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);
      }

      function addCirclesAtWireframeEnds(wireframe) {
                const circleGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.1, 40, 10);
                const circleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffffff });

                const vertices = wireframe.geometry.attributes.position.array;

                for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i += 6) {
                    const x = vertices[i];
                    const y = vertices[i +1 ];
                    const z = vertices[i + 2];

                    const circle = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeometry, circleMaterial);
                    circle.position.set(x, y, z);
                    scene.add(circle);
                }
            }


      function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
      }

      function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

        diamond.rotation.x += 0.005;
        diamond.rotation.y += 0.01;
        wireframe.rotation.x += 0.005;
        wireframe.rotation.y += 0.01;
      

        controls.update();

        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am so sorry for not putting cdn's, they don't seem to work, I amworking on this file in the three.js examples folder.

So this is my reference image of ideally what I would have liked as a shape
[image: disamond+wireframe]

And here would be the end result on each corner :
[image: sphere on wireframe intersection]

[image: This is my isosahedron rotating with the wireframe that is 1,5x bigger that the diamond and as you can see the sphere dont seem to stick to the wirefrane. The two chapes are rotating and a reactive to orbit controls but the spheres dont rotate.]

Answer (score 0):

Your wireframe is not "connected" with spheres.
Try this approach:

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script type="importmap">
  {
    "imports": {
      "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/build/three.module.js",
      "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.159.0/examples/jsm/"
    }
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    const icosahedronGeometry = new THREE.IcosahedronGeometry(1, 0);
    const diamondMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({ color: 0x00FFFF });
    const diamond = new THREE.Mesh(icosahedronGeometry, diamondMaterial);
    scene.add(diamond);
    const wireframe = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(icosahedronGeometry);
    const line = new THREE.LineSegments(wireframe);
    line.material.depthTest = false;
    line.material.opacity = 0.25;
    line.material.transparent = true;
    scene.add(line);
    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.enableDamping = true;
    controls.enabled = true;
    const intersections = wireframe.attributes.position.array;
    for (let i = 0; i < intersections.length; i += 6) {
        const x = intersections[i];
        const y = intersections[i + 1];
        const z = intersections[i + 2];

        const sGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.05, 8, 8);
        const sMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF });
        const s = new THREE.Mesh(sGeometry, sMaterial);
        s.position.set(x, y, z);
        scene.add(s);
    }
    const dL = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xFFFFFF, 1);
    dL.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
    scene.add(dL);
    camera.position.z = 5;

    const rotationSpeed = 0.002;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        diamond.rotation.x += rotationSpeed;
        diamond.rotation.y += rotationSpeed;
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    animate();
    window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
        const newWidth = window.innerWidth;
        const newHeight = window.innerHeight;
        camera.aspect = newWidth / newHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize(newWidth, newHeight);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the diamond not transparent so we don't see all the confusing lines of the wireframe And the circles are deformed and not spheres with shade, and for rotation, I can just add it.    ```wireframe.rotation.x += rotationSpeed;
       wireframe.rotation.y += rotationSpeed;```

Comment: What do you mean “diamond transparent”? You mean wireframe?